# HttpOperationHandlerFactory and InputParameters issue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, asp.net-web-api

I've written a custom OperationHandler for my WCF WebAPI project as follows:

```
public class AuthenticationOperationHandler : HttpOperationHandlerFactory
{
    protected override Collection<HttpOperationHandler> OnCreateRequestHandlers(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, HttpOperationDescription operation)
    {
        var baseHandlers = base.OnCreateRequestHandlers(endpoint, operation);

        if (operation.InputParameters.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower() == "username").Any() &&
            operation.InputParameters.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower() == "password").Any())
        {
            baseHandlers.Add(new AuthenticateRequestHandler(string.Format("{0}:{1}", operation.InputParameters.Where(p => p.Name == "username").First                           ().Name, operation.InputParameters.Where(p => p.Name == "password").First().Name)));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }

        return baseHandlers;
    }
}
```

As well as this custom RequestHandler which is added to the pipeline:

```
public class AuthenticateRequestHandler : HttpOperationHandler<HttpRequestMessage, string>
{
    public AuthenticateRequestHandler(string outputParameterName)
        : base(outputParameterName)
    {
    }

    public override string OnHandle(HttpRequestMessage input)
    {
        var stringValue = input.Content.ReadAsString();
        var username = stringValue.Split(':')[0];
        var password = stringValue.Split(':')[1];

        var isAuthenticated = ((BocaMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).ValidateUser(username, password);
        if (!isAuthenticated)
        {
            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }

        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

and this is my API Implementation:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class CompanyService
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST")]
    public bool Post(string username, string password)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My configuration in Global.asax file is

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    var config = HttpHostConfiguration.Create().SetOperationHandlerFactory(new AuthenticationOperationHandler());
    routes.MapServiceRoute<AuthenticationService>("login", config);
    routes.MapServiceRoute<CompanyService>("companies", config);
}
```

When trying to send a POST request to /companies I receive the following error message:

> The HttpOperationHandlerFactory is unable to determine the input
>   parameter that should be associated with the request message content
>   for service operation 'Post'. If the operation does not expect content
>   in the request message use the HTTP GET method with the operation.
>   Otherwise, ensure that one input parameter either has it's
>   IsContentParameter property set to 'True' or is a type that is
>   assignable to one of the following: HttpContent, ObjectContent`1,
>   HttpRequestMessage or HttpRequestMessage`1.

on this line:

```
var baseHandlers = base.OnCreateRequestHandlers(endpoint, operation);
```

Any idea why this happens and how to fix this in order to force user send username/password parameters in each and every request and validate it against the Membership API afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, your UriTemplate property is empty, which is why an exception is thrown.  It should be set as follows:

```
UriTemplate = "&username={username}&password={password}"
```

There's still a bug in your code because both input parameters receive the same string, namely *username=JohnDoe:password=qwerty*

To solve your problem, this is a good [article](http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/wcf-web-api-self-hosting-https-and-http-basic-authentication/) on how to implement HTTP basic authentication with WCF Web API.